# How to prevent IE from loading hidden content using HTML/CSS only?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

When you set an html element to have **`display: none`**, the content inside that element (e.g. images and flash) wont be loaded by Firefox until the element is set to be displayed.
But Internet Explorer dont behave like that. It loads everything inside hidden elements from start.

Is there a way to prevent IE from loading such content without using javascript?

Comment: When you say, "It loads everything inside hidden elements from start," do you mean it is displaying them or simply creating the nodes, albeit hidden, in the DOM?

Comment: no, the browser doesn't display that content, but IE does load external files such as images and flash animations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As my question regarded a solution not using javascript, I'll answer my own question and just say there is no way so far to prevent IE from loading external files that are part of hidden content.

As the other answers suggest it, there are ways to avoid the problem, but not to solve it. So the answer to my specific question is "NO".

Comment: The reason people aren't giving you a straight answer is because, from your question, it sounds like you're going to be using javascript anyway. So why exactly do you have this requirement that no JS should be used?

Comment: I always try to avoid using javascript. Many of today's web pages are a complete mess because of javascript abuse (which causes frequent browser freezes). Sometimes you just want to know if something is possible or not. If it's not, then you find a workaround. But you should always try the simplest way first.

Answer (score 3):

Don't insert any content into that element? Only load it using ajax when the user makes is visible.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you set the visibility to hidden, ie won't load it.

Comment: Really? by setting display:none IE downloads images and flash animations but by setting visibility:hidden it wont? I'll have to try that.

Comment: This is true in IE9+, it's currently causing me hassle

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what ZippyV is talking about (with a twist)... copy and paste the code below into a new file with an HTML extension and run it!

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is the title</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<div id="hidden-content"></div>
<p>Another paragraph</p>
<input type="button" id="add-content" value="Add Hidden Content" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add-content").click(
            function() {
                var info = unescape('%53%68%68%68%2E%2E%2E%20%73%65%63%72%65%74%20%69%6E%66%6F%72%6D%61%74%69%6F%6E');
                $("#hidden-content").html(info);
            }
        );
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The twist is that the hidden content to be displayed is first escaped (using the Javascript escape() function).  Also, you can place the javascript in a separate file!

Answer (score -1):

`display: none` should be hiding the element contents from ie as well as any other browsers.

Did you close all the tags?

Answer (score -1):

```
function hide_show_content(el_ID){

        //try <element hidden> property NOT IExplorer
        try{el_ID.hidden = ((el_ID.hidden) ? false : true);}catch(_e){}
        //try style=display:none for IExplorer
        try{
            if(el_ID.style.display==""){return;}
            el_ID.style.display = ((el_ID.style.display=="none") ? "inherit" : "none");
        }catch(_e){}

    }



<span id="text#1"  style="display:none;" hidden>TEXT TO BE HIDDEN or SHOWN laiter.</span>

<a href="" onClick="hide_show_content(document.getElementById('text#1')); return false;">Click to show TEXT</a>
```

Comment: The question says "HTML/CSS only", which means... no javascript.